# Getting SOAP response in PHP even if value is not set

Tags: php, xml, soap

I don't work with PHP very often, at least not at this level, so I need some help. I have a SOAP response in PHP that turns into an Object:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [Food_Document] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Food_Type] => Fruit
        [Food_Serial] => 923490123
        [Food_Name] => Apple
        [Food_PictureName] => rotten_apple.jpg
        [Food_PictureData] => sdlkff90sd9f90af9903r90wegf90asdtlj34kljtklsmdgkqwe4otksgk
    )

)
```

What I need is the data from Food_PictureName and Food_PictureData, but it explodes with a warning every time I try to access it if it doesn't exist. Some objects will contain Food_PictureName and Food_PictureData, but not all of the time. Sometimes, only one or the other will exist, or neither. Basically, "0 or more times."

Here's the code I'm using:

```
function get_food_photo($serial)
{
    $soap = new SoapClient("WSDL_LINK", array('trace' => true));
    $params = new StdClass;
    $params->serialNumber = $serial;  // or whatever serial number you choose

    $res = $soap->GetFoodDocuments($params);
    $res = $res->GetFoodDocumentsResult;


    $thumbnail_data = $res->FoodDocument[0]->Food_PictureData;
    $ext = str_replace('.', '', $res->FoodDocument[0]->Food_PictureExtension);
    return '<img src="data:image/'.$ext.';base64,'.$thumbnail_data.'"/>';
}
```

Now, accessing this data and displaying it DOES work if the Food_PictureData property is not null or empty, but otherwise, it will generate a warning every time: **Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array**

I have tried the following: isset(), empty(), property_exists(), __isset(), strlen(), and some others.

How do I get this data without throwing an exception if it doesn't exist?

Comment: Can you give the code where you are trying to access the property.

Comment: Just added that! Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite the function as

```
function get_food_photo($serial)
{
    $soap = new SoapClient("WSDL_LINK", array('trace' => true));
    $params = new StdClass;
    $params->serialNumber = $serial;  // or whatever serial number you choose

    $res = $soap->GetFoodDocuments($params);
    $res = $res->GetFoodDocumentsResult;

    if (is_array($res->FoodDocument)) {
        $document = $res->FoodDocument[0];
    } else {
        $document = $res->FoodDocument;
    }

    if (property_exists($document, 'Food_PictureData')) {
        $thumbnail_data = $document->Food_PictureData;
    } else {
        $thumbnail_data = '';
    }

    if (property_exists($document, 'Food_PictureExtension')) {
        $ext = str_replace('.', '', $document->Food_PictureExtension);
    } else {
        $ext = '';
    }

    return '<img src="data:image/'.$ext.';base64,'.$thumbnail_data.'"/>';
}
```

Comment: I tried that. Error on the following: $res->FoodDocument[0], $res, $res->FoodDocument, $res->FoodDocument->FoodPictureData. Can't access any of it if it doesn't exist. Property_exists() also doesn't work.

Comment: @heh I am missing a piece of the puzzle. I have created an object based on your `print_r` result but I do not get any errors when checking the existence of a property. Is the print_r taken from `$res`?

Comment: Warning: First parameter must either be an object or the name of an existing class in "C:\website\food_picture.php"

Comment: Yes, the print_r is taken from $res. It works if the property exists, but only if I use "$res->FoodDocument[0]." However, if I use a serial number that doesn't have a Food_PictureData field, it will explode with this error: **Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array**

Comment: So the dump in your answer is coming from print_r on `$res->TrademarkDocument[0]` and not `$res`?

Comment: Nope, the dump is coming from $res.

Comment: It does not make any sense unless `FoodDocument` sometimes refer to a single object and sometines to an array of objects.

Comment: Actually, it does.. sometimes it's a single object (FoodDocument[0]), and sometimes it's multiple FoodDocuments[0-3]. What is the best way to handle it?

Comment: That is not what I mean. When you use FoodDocument[0] it refers to an array of objects even though there is just one object in the array. The dump in your question does not refer to an array but directly to an object.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that's what you were referring to. It does have 0 or more documents inside of the array, but it does not have more than one object inside of it. It doesn't make sense to me as to why I can't check if it exists or not if it doesn't exist (throws a fatal error). None of us can figure this out.

With your code, it produces: **Warning: First parameter must either be an object or the name of an existing class**

Comment: I have rewritten the function. Can you try that one.

Comment: That works perfectly for the most part. Thank you very much, Barry! I've modified it to suit my needs. Now I just need to figure out the rest of the errors.

Comment: Huh...

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$FoodDocument on line 17 (**if (is_array($res->TrademarkDocument))**) 
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$FoodDocument on line 23 (**$document = $res->TrademarkDocument;**)

Comment: You have to check first if TradeDocument exists: if (property_exists($res, 'TradeDocument')) {}`.